# Draw a custom border using selector with Animation

Tags: android, user-interface, android-selector

I'm using a recyclerview which contains n horizontal elements within. Each is an image and some text. You traverse the menu using a d-pad (physical arrow keys) and **not** a touch screen.

I'd like to achieve the following effect using the Android xml selector, and can't figure out how:

- In the `unselected_state`, I'd like the elements to remain as is.
- In the active, or `selected_state`, I'd like the green crosshair (not sure what to call it) to show up using a fade in animation
- Fade out when an element goes back to the `unselected_state`.

I tried using a nine-patch but got weird results, and I'm not sure if that's the right way to do this.
My current selector uses simple colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Checked tab -->
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/red" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Active tab -->
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- Inactive tab -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false">
    <color android:color="@color/black_faded" />
</item>
<!-- Pressed tab -->
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <color android:color="@color/black_faded" />
</item>
<!-- Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true">
    <color android:color="@color/red" />
</item>
</selector>
```

[image]

Comment: You have only 5 items?

Comment: For now, yes. But it'll be scrollable later, so I don't want to use static content / a scrollview or hardcoded items.

Comment: Use a view in adapter and animate that view if item is selected

Comment: That'd be a lot of manual work, which is why I though using `selector` is the easiest/standard Android way.